# When I input a number into jTextField1, the case does not get acted upon

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement

eg. I input 1 into `combobox` and 50 into `jTextField1` and the correct answer won't come out. It is going to be code that runs an application to convert chosen temperature ie. celcius, fairenheit or kelvin into the desired choice. For now I'm just trying out with this format of the choices between 1 and 4. I will change it later. `Jbutton1` is the button to convert and when clicked should enact all the code within it. but for some reason it does not want to enact on the case that I defined earlier on. It should take the inputted temperature and add 273 to it.

```
public class Conversion extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int calculation = 0;
    String temphold;
    double input_temp;

    /**
     * Creates new form Conversion
     */
    public Conversion() {
        initComponents();
    }


    public void cases() {
       switch (calculation) {
         case 1: 
          input_temp = input_temp + 273.5;
         break;           
       }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(126, 126, 126)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(207, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(67, 67, 67))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        temphold = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String hold = jTextField1.getText();
        input_temp = Double.parseDouble(hold);
        if (temphold == "1") {
            calculation = 1;
            System.out.println("monkey");
            System.out.println(input_temp);
        }


    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Conversion.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Conversion().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: What is the console output? Does "monkey" and the temperature get printed?

Comment: your cases() method is never called

Comment: @NomadMaker yes the temperature and monkey get outputted, but the temperature is never changed like it shld be in my case 'calculation'

Comment: Claus Radloff, have i not already by defining the case 'calculation' in public void cases (). and Called it within the if statement by saying calculation = 1;

Comment: You need to call cases() in actionPerformed.